# How to solve (mismatched types string and byte) in Golang

Tags: string, go, byte

```
func g(str string) string {
    var i = 0
    var new_str = ""
    for i < len(str) - 1 {
        new_str = new_str + str[i + 1]
        i = i + 1
}

func f(str string) string {
if len(str) == 0 {
    return ""
} else {
    if len(str) == 1 {
        return str
    } else {
        return f(g(str)) + str[0]
    }
}

func h(n uint64, str string) string {
for n != 1 {
    if n % 2 == 0 {
        n = n / 2
    } else {
        n = 3*n + 1
    }
    str = f(str)
}
return str
}


func pow(x, y uint64) uint64 {
if y == 0 {
    return 1
} else {
    return x * pow(x, y-1)
}
}


func main() {
fmt.Println(h(1, "fruits"))
fmt.Println(h(2, "fruits"))
fmt.Println(h(5, "fruits"))
fmt.Println(h(pow(2, 1000000000000000), "fruits"))
fmt.Println(h(pow(2, 1000000000000000), "fruits"))
}
```

> ## command-line-arguments
>
> > .\fruits.go:11:21: invalid operation: new_str + str[i + 1] (mismatched types string and byte)
> >     .\fruits.go:24:21: invalid operation: f(g(str)) + str[0] (mismatched types string and byte)

Comment: You should try to make it as easy as possible for people to help you. Your code doesn't compile because of unrelated errors. It's not a minimal example of your problem. Here's a simple, near minimal example that illustrates your problem: https://play.golang.org/p/5AypoIALwNv  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6):

The error message describes your problem: `invalid operation: new_str + str[i + 1] (mismatched types string and byte)`. `str[i + 1]` is a byte from the underlying `str` array. Go requires explicit conversions. Write `string(str[i + 1])`.

For example,

```
package main

func g(str string) string {
    var i = 0
    var new_str = ""
    for i < len(str)-1 {

        // invalid operation: new_str + str[i + 1] (mismatched types string and byte)
        // new_str = new_str + str[i+1]

        new_str = new_str + string(str[i+1])
        i = i + 1
    }
    return new_str
}

func main() {}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/E9-n7IO-Q_z